# Check if array can be matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

Say we have an array of length 9. This can be a matrix.

```
[
1,2,3,
4,5,6
7,8,9
]
```

If we have an array or length 10, this can't be a matrix.

```
[
1,2,3,
4,5,6
7,8,9,10
]
```

How can I determine whether the given array can be a proper matrix using JS?

Comment: What is the definition of "matrix"? Why 10 can't be a matrix(e.g. 2x5)? Are the columns and rows have to be the same?

Comment: Yes, even number of 'columns' and 'rows'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web

Comment: Then it's simply a question of determining whether the length is a square number i.e. 4, 9, 16, 25 etc.

Comment: True! IDK why I didn't think of that lol

Comment: The solution can be simplified as: `const isMatrix = arr => arr.length > 1 && !(arr.length ** 0.5 % 1)`

Answer (score 1):

1) Determine which number (greater than 1, and less than the array's length) can be used to divide the array into even chunks/rows by creating a new chucked array.

2) Check if all evenly divided chunks/rows are equal to the parent array's length.

```
const chunk = (arr, n) => { 
    const newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        let lastAdded = newArr[newArr.length - 1] || null;
        if (lastAdded != null && lastAdded.length != n) { 
            lastAdded.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            newArr.push([arr[i]]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
const ismatrix = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (i > 1) {
            if (arr.length % i === 0) {
                let chunked = chunk(arr, i);         
                for (let i = 0; i < chunked.length; i++) {
                    if (chunked.length == chunked[i].length) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
    return false
}
```